# Need Advice about Object Relational Mapping

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, orm, nosql

i need your advice. I build backend rest api project for myself for learning purpose right now. I'm using Node JS with MongoDB. Already implement many features for my mini project.

So, do i have/need to implement ORM in my Node JS app for learning purpose? since i know that MongoDB is NoSQL and the MongoDB itself doesn't need a relational thing but still curious and wondering about ORM works (I used to implement ORM when learning Java).

And i want to learn deeply about containerizing, is the ORM-things impact so much on containerizing? or will it causing error too much in my Node JS app?

Looking the answer and explanation from you, thanks

Comment: You can connect to MongoDB using NodeJS Driver. There is no ORM for MongoDB NodeJS. But, there is an ODM (Object Data Mapping) software - is is called Mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

> So, do i have/need to implement ORM in my Node JS app for learning purpose?

That's up to you, and the question does not provide enough context to form any educated advice.

> is the ORM-things impact so much on containerizing?

I doubt the presence of an ORM will impact containerization much if at all. A well-implemented app would not have any sort of coupling between something internal to the implementation of its backend and its deployement environment and process. If anything, an ORM could potentially slow down data access operations (as it may prevent query and update optimization), which could impact backend response time. At a large scale this could become a factor in how you choose to deploy your backend, but again I doubt it will prevent containerization.

> will it causing error too much in my Node JS app?

No, the presence of an ORM will not inherently increase the error rate. In fact it may decrease errors as ORMs typically provide automatic handling  of common failure paths, and reduce the amount of code needed to accomplish operations, which decreases opportunities for developer mistakes.